# Karaf exception is thrown while installing org.fusesource.leveldbjni

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, karaf, opendaylight

Hi i am trying to install the below dependency in karaf

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.fusesource.leveldbjni</groupId>
    <artifactId>leveldbjni-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

I am getting the below Exception

```
Exception caught while executing command
org.apache.karaf.shell.console.MultiException: Error executing command on bundles:
    Unable to execute command on bundle 564: The bundle "org.fusesource.leveldbjni.leveldbjni-all_1.8.0 [564]" could not be resolved. Reason: No match found for native code: META-INF/native/windows32/leveldbjni.dll; processor=x86; osname=Win32, META-INF/native/windows64/leveldbjni.dll; processor=x86-64; osname=Win32, META-INF/native/osx/libleveldbjni.jnilib; processor=x86; osname=macosx, META-INF/native/osx/libleveldbjni.jnilib; processor=x86-64; osname=macosx, META-INF/native/linux32/libleveldbjni.so; processor=x86; osname=Linux, META-INF/native/linux64/libleveldbjni.so; processor=x86-64; osname=Linux
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.MultiException.throwIf(MultiException.java:92)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.doExecute(BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.java:58)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommand.doExecute(BundlesCommand.java:50)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.doExecute(BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.java:41)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:33)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.OsgiCommandSupport.execute(OsgiCommandSupport.java:39)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler$1.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:119)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.commands.$BlueprintCommand1099159826.execute(Unknown Source)[37:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.1]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler$1.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.ProxyHandler.invoke(ProxyHandler.java:119)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.commands.$BlueprintCommand1099159826.execute(Unknown Source)[37:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:78)[37:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:477)[37:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:403)[37:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[37:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)[37:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)[37:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.impl.jline.ConsoleImpl$DelegateSession.execute(ConsoleImpl.java:521)
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.impl.jline.ConsoleImpl.run(ConsoleImpl.java:212)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.impl.jline.ConsoleFactoryService$3.doRun(ConsoleFactoryService.java:126)[37:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.impl.jline.ConsoleFactoryService$3$1.run(ConsoleFactoryService.java:117)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_79]
    at org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.JaasHelper.doAs(JaasHelper.java:47)[38:org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules:3.0.1]
    at org.apache.karaf.shell.console.impl.jline.ConsoleFactoryService$3.run(ConsoleFactoryService.java:115)[37:org.apache.karaf.shell.console:3.0.1]
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to execute command on bundle 564: The bundle "org.fusesource.leveldbjni.leveldbjni-all_1.8.0 [564]" could not be resolved. Reason: No match found for native code: META-INF/native/windows32/leveldbjni.dll; processor=x86; osname=Win32, META-INF/native/windows64/leveldbjni.dll; processor=x86-64; osname=Win32, META-INF/native/osx/libleveldbjni.jnilib; processor=x86; osname=macosx, META-INF/native/osx/libleveldbjni.jnilib; processor=x86-64; osname=macosx, META-INF/native/linux32/libleveldbjni.so; processor=x86; osname=Linux, META-INF/native/linux64/libleveldbjni.so; processor=x86-64; osname=Linux
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.doExecute(BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.java:55)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.fusesource.leveldbjni.leveldbjni-all_1.8.0 [564]" could not be resolved. Reason: No match found for native code: META-INF/native/windows32/leveldbjni.dll; processor=x86; osname=Win32, META-INF/native/windows64/leveldbjni.dll; processor=x86-64; osname=Win32, META-INF/native/osx/libleveldbjni.jnilib; processor=x86; osname=macosx, META-INF/native/osx/libleveldbjni.jnilib; processor=x86-64; osname=macosx, META-INF/native/linux32/libleveldbjni.so; processor=x86; osname=Linux, META-INF/native/linux64/libleveldbjni.so; processor=x86-64; osname=Linux
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:292)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.Start.executeOnBundle(Start.java:27)
    at org.apache.karaf.bundle.command.BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.doExecute(BundlesCommandWithConfirmation.java:53)
    ... 32 more
```

I am trying to install some opendaylight features and one of the features internally uses this dependency. Am i missing out something please help.

Comment: the error says it can't find native library for your processor/os. What is the value of the properties `org.osgi.framework.os.name` and `org.osgi.framework.os.processor` (you can see them with the command `system:property`)

Comment: org.osgi.framework.os.name=window 8.1
org.osgi.framework.os.version=6.3.0
I can find the value for the property org.osgi.framework.os.processor

Comment: The stacktrace is saying it is not able to find the dll. The dll is part of the dependency jar itself. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/l/Downloadleveldbjniall17jar.htm. FYI i have taken the opendaylight karaf distribution. https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/org/opendaylight/integration/distribution-karaf/0.4.0-SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bundle "leveldbjni" has a dependency on a "native" library. Native as in "os dependent". In OSGi, a bundle can declare several natives libraries, and specify, for each library, when this library can be loaded.

In your error, you can see which library this bundle can load:

- `windows32/leveldbjni.dll` if processor=x86; osname=Win32
- `windows64/leveldbjni.dll` if processor=x86-64; osname=Win32
- `osx/libleveldbjni.jnilib` if processor=x86; osname=macosx
- `osx/libleveldbjni.jnilib` if processor=x86-64; osname=macosx
- `linux32/libleveldbjni.so` if processor=x86; osname=Linux
- `linux64/libleveldbjni.so` if processor=x86-64; osname=Linux

In your case, osname="Windows 8.1", so there is no library matching this name, and the requirement fails.

Each OSGi framework has a list of "alias" for mapping osname-s. It depends on your implementation (and versions). For example, the [latest version of Equinox](https://github.com/eclipse/rt.equinox.framework/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.osgi/container/src/org/eclipse/osgi/internal/framework/osname.aliases) has this configuration:

```
Windows8 "Windows 8" "Windows 8.1" "Windows 8.2" "Windows 8.3" Win8 Win32 # Microsoft
```

In [Felix](https://github.com/apache/felix/blob/trunk/framework/src/main/resources/default.properties#L66) :

```
felix.native.osname.alias.windows8=windows 8,win32
```

I don't know which framework you use, or which version, but if you use Felix (which is the default), you can try to add, in the file `etc/system.properties` :

```
felix.native.osname.alias.windows8=windows 8,windows 8.1,win32
```

In Equinox, this issue is tracked on [Bug 423970](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=423970). I don't know how to override these properties. Karaf 4 has a version of Equinox which should work.

You can try, maybe, to override in `etc/system.properties` the value of the os (Honestly, I don't know if it will work as this value should be discovered - and it's an ugly hack to hardcode this value)

```
org.osgi.framework.os.name = Win32
```

Comment: In my karaf 4.0.3 i am not able to find this entry in system.properties. So should i add and see?

Comment: I have made the entry in system.properties. Karaf is still throwing the same error.

Comment: I didn't see, you use Equinox. This property is for Felix

Comment: I am using felix only. i have checked etc/config.properties (karaf.framework=felix)

Comment: check custom.properties. You are using Equinox, seeing your stacktrace : `org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle`

Comment: yes custom.properties its equinox. Is there a similar entry for equinox?

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible in Equinox to override this property - at least in the version of Equinox shipped with Karaf 3.0.1. I have updated my answer with the tracked issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, hardcode the OS in `etc/system.properties` by adding `org.osgi.framework.os.name = Win32` to it. This is the final advice from  Jeremie B's answer which did solve the issue for me.